# SwiftUI - ExpandableView inside VStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to have multiple expandable views with animation inside a VStack. I have the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ExpandableView(headerTitle: "First")
                    ExpandableView(headerTitle: "Second")
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the ExpandableView:

```
struct ExpandableView: View {
    let headerTitle: String
    @State private var collapsed: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(
            action: {
                self.collapsed.toggle()
            },
            label: {
                VStack(spacing: 2) {
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(.gray)
                        VStack {
                            Text("\(headerTitle) Header")
                            if !collapsed {
                                HStack {
                                    Text("Text A")
                                    Text("Text B")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(height: collapsed ? 52 : 80)
                    ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(.gray)
                            .frame(height: 204)
                        VStack {
                            Text("Content A")
                            Text("Content B")
                            Text("Content C")
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxHeight: collapsed ? 0 : .none)
                    .clipped()
                }
            }
        )
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        .animation(.easeOut, value: collapsed)
    }
}
```

The result is this:
[image]

As you can see if I open the last expandableView is opens correctly. However if I open the first one when the second is closed, it actually opens the second. It only opens correctly the first one if the second is already open. It seems the VStack is not rendering correctly itself. Any ideas why this happening?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: you can try DisclosureGroup https://serialcoder.dev/text-tutorials/swiftui/disclosure-group-in-swiftui/ or OutlineGroup https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/09/02/displaying-recursive-data-using-outlinegroup-in-swiftui/ instead of writing custom one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I migth be the way the buttons works. Here is a cleaner solution:

```
struct ExpandableView: View {
        let headerTitle: String
        @State private var collapsed: Bool = true
        
        var body: some View {
            
            VStack(spacing: 2) {
                
                Button(
                    action: {
                        withAnimation(.easeOut){
                            self.collapsed.toggle()
                        }
                    },
                    label: {
                        
                        VStack {
                            Text("\(headerTitle) Header")
                            if !collapsed {
                                HStack {
                                    Text("Text A")
                                    Text("Text B")
                                }
                            }
                        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    })
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .tint(.gray)
                
                if(!self.collapsed) {
                    VStack {
                        Divider().background(.black)
                        Text("Content A")
                        Text("Content B")
                        Text("Content C")
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(height: collapsed ? 52 : 204)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(.gray)
            .padding()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Absolutely correct answer. But I don't understand why, I see I have to be careful with  the button animations. I tried different versions, even removing the button and add a .onTapGesture in the VStack of the header, which happens another strange thing, the tap is not recognized in the VStack but only if tapped in the Text. Will select your answer as correct, thank you!

Comment: To fix that tapable area just do `.contentShape(Rectangle())`